# If statement for radiobutton's

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, radio-button

So I have 4 `radiobutton` and 3 of them will use the same items from the `checkbox` but the other one will show to the user other info after he check it. This is the code that I am using:

```
If rbPorData.Checked And rbPorExtensão.Checked And rbPorNome.Checked Then
        ShowInfoComboBox()
    ElseIf rbPcName.Checked Then
        ShowInfoComboBoxPcName()
End If
```

This is the code of one of the methods that I've called:

```
Private Sub ShowInfoComboBoxPcName()
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "........................"
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            Query = "SELECT PcName AS [NomePc]
                    FROM infofile 
                    GROUP BY PcName"
            SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            While SqlDR.Read
                Dim pcName = SqlDR.GetString(0)
                cbExtensão.Items.Add(pcName)
            End While
            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Where should I use this code to make this work? I've made some attempts to make this work and one of them was put the if statement into the form but it will does not work because I am using tabs.

Comment: How about in `CheckedChanged` ? Also, use a `Using` statement in place of your Dispose.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about the context but probably you need to use `OrElse` instead of `And` in your `If`, as otherwise all three radioboxes need to be ticked: `If rbPorData.Checked OrElse rbPorExtensão.Checked OrElse rbPorNome.Checked Then`

Comment: But where should I use it?? Into the form? @KeithMifsud

Comment: As @AndrewMortimer said, in your form, add a 'CheckedChanged' event, so everytime you tick a checkbox, the system will call your method. See my answer below:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .Net 'CheckedChanged' event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Private Sub rd_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbPorData.CheckedChanged, rbPorExtensão.CheckedChanged, rbPorNome.CheckedChanged, rbPcName.CheckedChanged
    If rbPorData.Checked OrElse rbPorExtensão.Checked OrElse rbPorNome.Checked Then
        ShowInfoComboBox()
    ElseIf rbPcName.Checked Then
        ShowInfoComboBoxPcName()
    End If
End Sub
```